# Firebase Device Token send to server with register form [Android]

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add `TokenID` in member data form but I don't know how to add it.

```
private void registerUser() {
    displayLoader();
    JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(Dashboard.this, new OnSuccessListener < InstanceIdResult > () {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
        String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
        Log.e("newToken", newToken);
      }
    });

    try {
      //Populate the request parameters
      request.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
      request.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
      request.put("deviceID", newToken); // <--- token

    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    [...]
```

How do I send `TokenID` together with the form?

Error:

```
error: cannot find symbol variable newToken
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error:

> error: cannot find symbol variable newToken

Because you are using the `newToken` String outside the scope that is initially defined. To solve this, just move that try-catch block inside the `onSuccess()` method right after this line of code:

```
Log.e("newToken", newToken);
```

And your problem will be solved.

Comment: I moved inside the `onSuccess()` but this time, I getting this error: > error: incompatible types: <anonymous OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>> cannot be converted to Context - I share all the code so I can show you the right way with this [link](https://pastebin.com/FmGaHTJ3)

Comment: Line: 169 - `MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);`

Comment: The fact that you get another error, it means that the initial error disappeared and this are good news :) but this sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment or using only the data above. As a personal guess, I think that you are using a wrong context but in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.